# Por qué whereBetween de laravel no cuenta el día de hoy

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy haciendo la exportación de datos a una excel con Laravel, quiero filtrar por un rango de fechas, pero hoy por ejemplo es día 29 de Junio, si pongo; filtra desde el 28 al 29 de Junio, me esta sacando los registros del 27, 28 pero no del 29 y no entiendo por que saca del día 27 y no del 29:

```
return  Orders::whereBetween('created_at', [$this->fecha_inicio, $this->fecha_fin])->select('ticket','total', 'created_at')->get();
```

Hay algo que me pierdo con `whereBetween`

Y una cosa más, hago un `select al created_at` ese select es que me imprime en la columna del excel, es posible darle formato en el mismo select.

Comment: Posiblemente la configuracion del server o de la BD esté en otra zona horaria, y justo coincide que para el momento en que haces la consulta, lo toma como el dia anterior. Prueba con `whereDateBetween` en vez de solo `whereBetween`. O hacer la comparacion manulmente con >= y <=  `whereDate('created_at','>=',$this->fecha_inicio)->whereDate('created_at','<=',$this->fecha_fin)`

Comment: Ah, mira lo que pasa con lo que mencionas del dia 29 : _El problema es que la columna `created_at` suele ser fecha y hora, por lo que no es una fecha simple sino que también tiene una hora. Lo que significa que, en la práctica, cualquier publicación creada el día 29 no se recuperará porque su fecha de creación siempre será posterior a 2023-06-29 (que SQL supondrá que significa '2023-06-29 00:00:00')_

Comment: Hola @porloscerrosΨ entonces lo más aconsejable es tener un campo de fecha única parece no, ya probé de forma manual y sucede lo mismo, si es verdad que el `created_at` que me imprime en el excel lo imprime con dos horas atrasadas, creo que voy a hacer eso, crear un campo fecha, solo con la fecha.... gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Vale. En general, lo que trato de lograr, es que el servidor este configurado en zona horaria UTC y la aplicacion configurada en la zona horaria correspondiente ([/config/app.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/f419821bd8cbc736ac6f9b2fce75a4e373a4b49f/config/app.php#L73)) a los usuarios que la usen. Pero eso a veces no es posible. En tu caso, ademas juegan los datos del excel que tal vez no esten en UTC y la aplicacion interpreta que sí, e intenta moverla a la zona que tiene configurada. Asi que la mejor solucion va a depender de tu criterio de acuerdo a los requerimientos que tengas

Comment: Al final he creado una columna nueva con la fecha y solo la fecha, así utilizo ese campo para mostrarlo y filtrarlo, y la aplicación la tengo en la localización correcta, el servidor no lo se, nunca lo he tocado.